# Script to change a color in all layers of a PSD file to another color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

Is it possible to loop through all layers (there are too many layers) and replace one color with another. Need automated approach, script or simple action.

```
Loop through all layers{
    Change Fill color A to X
    Change Text color A to X
}
```

Comment: Going to need some more information about what you are trying to replace. Is it a single element per layer or are you trying to search for a color, select that color and replace it?

Comment: Selecting a layer you can go to `Image > Adjustment > Replace color` to change a color, I need automation of this process if we have too many layers.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript [Adobe's scripting interface](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/tree/master/Documentation/Product%20specific%20Documentation/Photoshop%20Scripting).

Changing text colour A to X is straight forward (provided you have no groups than it get a bit more complex):

```
var colourA = "28bd98"; 
var colourY = "ff00ff"; 


changeFontColour(colourA, colourY);



function changeFontColour(X,Y)
{
  var numOfLayers = app.activeDocument.layers.length;

  // main loop
  for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
  {
    var thisLayer = app.activeDocument.layers[i];

    if (app.activeDocument.layers[i].kind == 'LayerKind.TEXT')
    {
      var currentFontCol = getFontColour(thisLayer);

      // alert(currentFontCol + "\n" + X);

      if (currentFontCol.toUpperCase() == X.toUpperCase())
      {

        var myColour = new SolidColor();
        var RGB = HEXtoRGB(Y);
        myColour.rgb.red = RGB[0];
        myColour.rgb.green = RGB[1];
        myColour.rgb.blue = RGB[2];

        // replace text colour
        thisLayer.textItem.color = myColour;
      }
    }
  } //end of loop
}

function getFontColour(alayer)
{
  var fontColor = alayer.textItem.color;
  return fontColor.rgb.hexValue;
}

function HEXtoRGB (hex)
{
  var c = 1
  if (hex.charAt(0) != "#") c = 0;

  var r = parseInt(hex.substring(c,c+2),16)
  var g = parseInt(hex.substring(c+2,c+4),16)
  var b = parseInt(hex.substring(c+4,c+6),16)
  return [r, g, b];
}
```